# Get site url and updates data, then use them

Tags: plugins, updates

i need to get the url wordpress site and the updates avaible on that site. after get these data use it. to test if i get them I tried to echo in the footer.

theoretically I should be able to echo $update

```
    //
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_function' );

        function my_function() {
        $updates = wp_get_update_data();
         echo $updates['counts']['title'];
        echo get_site_url();
        echo 'hello world';
        }
```

but with it don't echo the number and what need update, but echo only url and hello world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should perform `$updates = wp_get_update_data();` in the `wp_footer()` body because till then you don't have access to `$updates` variables.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_function' );
function my_function() {
    $updates = wp_get_update_data();
    echo $updates['title'];
}
```

Comment: yes, i was just editing the question sorry

Comment: thank you, it's working without the 'count'